How to serialize a date to a specific format?
The mandatory output format of any date in a JSON string is:
{
    "element": [
        "~#date",
        [
            "2013-05-31"
        ]
    ],
    ...
}

I have to adhere to this specific format.
Building an object with an array of objects will not work. I get something like this:
{
    "element": [
        {
            "~#date": "2024-09-17"
        }
    ],
    ...
}

I could write a Serializer for LocalDate printing the '[...]'. That feels like cheating. Notice that the number of dates is always 1.
Is there a standard way of doing this?
This is what I did so far:
The object contains:
@JsonProperty("aDate")
private MyMDate[] myDate = null;

With 'MyDate' being:
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyDate {
    @JsonProperty("~#date")
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateArraySerializer.class)
    private LocalDate[] date;
}

And the serializer:
public class LocalDateArraySerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate[]> {
    private final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate[] values, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        String seperator = "";
        for ( LocalDate ld: values) {
            gen.writeString( seperator + ld.format(format));
            seperator = ",";
        }
    }
}

This gives the actual output: an array with an object. That is not the requested output.

If you mean to handle multiple date values in an array, why do you show only a single value in your examples?

Are you saying that the output requires an array where the first element is the name of the attribute (i.e. ~#date ) and the second element is an array of values (where there's always one value)?

There will always be only 1 date. The format of the output is mandatory. I didn't devise it, yes it is weird, but I have to adhere to it.

In Java I would then model that by declaring element a List<Object> and give it the value List.of("~#date", List.of(LocalDate.of(2013, Month.MAY, 31))). Can‘t you get someting like that to work? (Use arrays instead of lists if you prefer.)

@tm1701 I gave a solution using custom serializer. Please try it and let me know.

"The mandatory output format of any date in a JSON string is ..." -- is that true? AFAIK the values of JSON are only object, array, number, or string - no defined format for dates. Also your example shows an array, why would a date start with the array delimiter [ ?

This is a mandatory format we have to adhere to.

You just need these lines :
public class CustomLocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDate> {

public CustomLocalDateSerializer() {
    super(LocalDate.class);
}

@Override
public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartArray();   // start outer array
    gen.writeString("~#date");
    gen.writeStartArray();   // start inner array
    gen.writeString(value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))); //date format
    gen.writeEndArray();     // end inner array
    gen.writeEndArray();     // end outer array
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = CustomLocalDateSerializer.class)
public class DateHolder {
private LocalDate date;

public DateHolder(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date;
}

// getters and setters
}

and then call the custom serializer
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

DateHolder dateHolder = new DateHolder(LocalDate.of(2013, 5, 31));
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(dateHolder); //serialize
System.out.println(json);


This is not enough to handle the OPs question as the element array contains values of different types.  This answer, as currently-written, will not resolve that issue

@blurfus i modified my answer and the only solution is a custom serializer.

The new answer helped me most, thank you! +1 +v

You can archive this with something like:
public class Awkward implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Object[] element;

    public Awkward() {
        super();
        
        element = new Object[2];
        
        String awkwardDate = "~#date";
        element[0] = awkwardDate;

        String[] awkwardValue = new String[1];
        awkwardValue[0] = "2013-05-31";

        element[1] = awkwardValue;
    }
...

Jackson will serialize this as:
{
  "element": [
    "~#date",
    ["2013-05-31"]
  ]
}


This is not intended to be a effective solution, just a way to show how JSON structure should be obtained in Java implementation.
Important part is:

an object with

a member named "element" whith

an array of values composed by

a string value "~#date"
a array of values composed by

a string value from a date formated as 'YYYY-MM-DD'






others irrelevant members...




Forgive the fun. ;)

Send my regrets to him, @tm1701 ;)

Thank you for helping! +1

I‘d (still) use LocalDate[] awkwardValue = { LocalDate.of(2013, Month.MAY, 31) };. With SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS disabled and jackson-modules-java8 added, Jackson should serialize the date as 2013-05-31 (ISO 8601 format).
